# Cordova@6.1.1 emulate android is stuck to load

Tags: android, cordova, emulation

There is a bug on cordova@6.1.1 when emulate android its stuck in emulate process, this problem happens before in some last versions but the code of emulate.js is different now. there is anyone can help ? 
[image]

Comment: What plugins are you using? Found similar issue in this link - https://github.com/intercom/intercom-cordova/issues/48 which is pertaining to issue in plugin

Comment: without any plugin install ... just creating a new fresh project and try to emulate android. its stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the problem. as I'm new in cordova and android, I installed new android studio that come with android v.6 and cordova using their emulator but cordova using andriod@5.1.1 so what I dome change the emulator version. :)